# Не так уж неплох ― это ошибка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

"По его словам, все они (местные рестораны) были не так уже неплохи, но, разумеется, не могли сравниться с "Боманьер"...(П. Мейл. Год в Провансе, перевод с англ.).

Ошибка? Но почему ошибся переводчик? Это чисто русская формула: не так уж плох ― это хорош, не так уж хорош ― это плох? Почему мы говорим именно так?

Интересно также, какой смысл эта фраза имеет в оригинале.

Comment: Вы же не привели фразу в оригинале. И, собственно, неясно, о чем вы спрашиваете. "Не так уж плох" и "хорош" (как и наоборот) – это всё же разные вещи. Не так уж плох – это примерно "сойдёт", "сгодится". До "хорошего" далеко. А ошибиться мог (и скорее всего так и было) не переводчик, а наборщик. Кстати, "уже" вместо "уж" – ваша ошибка или тоже наборщика?

Comment: Я спрашиваю: 1) Не так уж неплох ― это ошибка? 2) Почему мы используем слово "плохой", когда даем положительную оценку. 3) Сложно ли такую фразу понять иностранцу?

Comment: Ошибка. Понять просто, в других языках тоже есть подобные конструкции.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. Но я использовала программу перевода, и получила в результате was not so good, но это неверный смысл. Поэтому я не уверена, что здесь случайная ошибка, мне кажется, это непонимание русской фразы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> По его словам, все они были не так уж неплохи, но, разумеется, не могли сравниться с «Боманьер» в Лe- Бо. «Боманьер» удостоился трех мишленовских звезд и семнадцати очков из двадцати возможных по ресторанному гиду Го-Мийо, и там, уверял месье Баньоль, ему довелось попробовать совершенно исключительного морского окуня en croûte. (https://yelena-arefa.livejournal.com/20376.html#/20376.html)

Разумеется (см. контекст), сравнивается хорошее с еще лучшим. Поэтому только так:

**...все они были не так уж плохи...**

Дополнение.

А вот и [оригинал](http://usuaris.tinet.cat/palonso/llibres/mayle_peter-a%20year%20in%20provence.pdf):

> Each day precisely at noon he changed out of his overalls
>   and took himself off to one of the local restaurants for two hours.
>   He judged it to be not bad, but of course nothing like the Beaumanič re at Les Baux.

Так что я бы перевел так:

**Каждый день ровно в полдень месье Баньоль снимал свой рабочий комбинезон, переодевался и на два часа отправлялся в один из местных ресторанов. И каждый раз он говорил, что ресторан неплох, но не идет ни в какое сравнение  с «Боманьер» в Лe-Бо.**

Comment: Вы проделали большую работу. Спасибо за подсказку. Мой голос ― Вам. P. S. Надо бы ещё **Лe- Бо** (дефис) в тексте подправить.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо! Я поправил в своем переводе, а остальное - цитата.

Answer (score 2):

[Неплохой](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-44257.htm) ― достаточно хороший, удовлетворительный; недурной.

Мне кажется, что [вот этот](https://www.litres.ru/piter-meyl/god-v-provanse-6601039/chitat-onlayn/page-2/) перевод правильный:
*По его словам, все они были **вполне неплохи**, но, разумеется, не могли сравниться с «Боманьер» в Ле-Бо.*

*Те были третьего поколения, вполне неплохи и годились в дело* (В. Поселягин. Искатель).

*Кораблики были вполне неплохи. С хорошим ходом, с отличной броней, с турбинной силовой установкой и великолепными приборами управления огнем* (Р. Злотников. Взлет).

Comment: Переводчик: Ирина Пандер

Comment: Спасибо. А я искала-искала ― не нашла.

Comment: О книге здесь: https://www.litres.ru/piter-meyl/god-v-provanse-6601039/

Comment: Браво, Римма! Вывод: Не читайте и не обсуждайте непроверенные источники.

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо, уже выцарапала.